Proving the fundemental theorem of Calculus
I am currently trying to write a proof for the fundemental theorem of Calculus, mainly to practice writing proofs, and I have an attempt below. The problem is, I am unsure of how to interpret the result (and unsure how to adress certain assumptions). Also, I am not very well-versed in mathematics in general, so I might be using notation in a no-no fashion.
Let $f$ be a function which is continous on the interval $[a,b]$. For simplicity, we shall also assume that $f,f'\ge0$ over the given interval. Then, the set $P[a, b] =\{ (x,y):a\le x\le b,0\le y\le f(x) \}$ will be measureable with the following "area-measure":
$\displaystyle \mu(P[a,b])=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n})\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}$
Fix a point $a\lt c\lt$b. Then, the area between the point $x=c$ and some point $x=c+h$, for some fitting  $h>0$, can be expressed by:
$\displaystyle \mu(P[a,c+h])-\mu(P[a,c])$
Because of the function's monotonicity, and the fact that it's non-negative, we can create the following inequalities:
$\displaystyle hf(c)\le\displaystyle \mu(P[a,c+h])-\mu(P[a,c])\le hf(c+h)$
Dividing by $h$ and applying a limit where $h\to 0$, one obtains:
$\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} f(c)\le \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mu(P[a,c+h])-\mu([P(a,c)])}{h}\le\lim_{h \to 0} f(c+h)$
Since both the LHS and the RHS simplfiy to $f(c)$, we can infer by the squeeze theorem that:
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial }{\partial c}\mu(P[a,c])=f(c)$
This differential equation has a class of solutions, namely:
$\mu(P[a,c]) = F(c)+C$, where C is some real constant.
I am unsure how to interpret this. The result I was expecting was something along the lines of $F(c)+C-(F(a)+C)=F(c)-F(a)$, but I am not sure how to arrive here.
Also, I made some assumptions in the beginning, such as $f,f'\ge 0$, mainly to get nice inequalities. I suppose if $f'<0$, one could simply flip the inequality symbols, but that seems clunky. Is there some more elegant way to do it?
Lastly, I am unsure whether I should be using an area measure and a point set here, or if it's better to just create a map $A:a,b\mapsto \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n})\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}$. Not sure if it really matters, but I have never seen someone differentiate a measure like that. Frankly, I am not even sure if it's possible to do.

$f'$ should not be assumed to even exist. Moreover, even if it exists, it might be neither always $\ge0$ nor always $<0$.

@AnneBauval, I see. Should I perhaps add the condition that $f$ is differentiable over the interval, not only continuous? Also, the monotonicity is simply an assumption to make it easier for myself. I would like to adress the fact that its monotonicity might change after I have successfully proven it for this case.


No, you should not. You should prove the FTC under its usual hypothesis, not stronger ones. 2) Monotonicity is also an additional hence unwanted hypothesis. A continuous (or even differentiable) function can be non-piecewise monotonic. Example: $x^2\sin\frac1x$.


Try to prove first that ($\forall a\le u\le v\le b$)$$\mu(P[a,u])+\mu(P[u,v])=\mu(P[a,v]).$$ This will allow you to replace your inequalities with a use of the continuity of $f$ at $c$ in your approximation of $\mu(P[a,c+h])-\mu(P[a,c])$.

You haven't proved that the area measure is a measure. You are using the measure corresponding to the Lebesgue-Stieljes integral of $f$, which as the Wikipedia page notes, can be recovered from Carathéodory's extension theorem. In general, the bounds for $\mu([a, c+h]) - \mu([a,c])$ are wrong since both $f(c)$ and $f(c + h)$ can be zero while the values in between nonzero; you'd have to replace it with a limsup of $f(c + t)$ over all $0 \leq t \leq h$ as $h\to 0$.
When you make the claim that $g' = f$ has a set of solutions $F + C$, you should note that you have an explicit solution $g_0(x) = \mu([a, x])$. The quantity is the (signed) area under the graph of $f$ which you also know to be $\int_a^x f$, and thus you've proven some aspect of the fundamental theorem of calculus.
None of these are particularly good arguments; you're already using a lot more complicated machinery to prove a simple result. It's not bad that you attempted your own proof, but I believe that you should focus on studying a correct proof now. The fundamental theorem of calculus page on Wikipedia is an excellent place to learn about it. Another proof can be found on pp. 222-224 §88 of A Course Of Higher Mathematics Vol 1 Elementary Calculus by V.I. Smirnov which is an excellent book.

As advised in my last comment:

Prove first that$$∀a≤u≤v≤b
\quad
μ(P[a,u])+μ(P[u,v])=μ(P[a,v]).$$
This will allow you to replace your inequalities with a use of the continuity of $f$
at $c$
in your approximation of $μ(P[a,c+h])−μ(P[a,c])$.


The first step becomes obvious if you use the following more general limit than yours: for any continuous function $f$ (or more generally for any regulated function on $[a,b]$), $f$ is Riemann integrable and your $\mu(P[a,b])$ equals
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{\delta\to0}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i)\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right),$$
where the limit is taken over all tagged partitions $a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_i<\dots<x_n=b$, $t_i\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ such that $x_{i+1}-x_i\le\delta$.
Defining $F(c):=\int_a^cf(x)dx$, you can then derive $$\left|F(c+h)-F(c)-hf(c)\right|=\left|\int_c^{c+h}\left(f(x)-f(c)\right)dx\right|$$
and use that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\eta>0$ such that
$|x-c|\le\eta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|\le\epsilon$, hence
$$|h|\le\eta\implies\left|\int_c^{c+h}\left(f(x)-f(c)\right)dx\right|\le\epsilon|h|\implies\left|\frac{F(c+h)-F(c)}h-f(c)\right|\le\epsilon,$$
q.e.d.

